# How to validate an instance with dynamic code in rails 3.2 model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

We need to validate a model `instance` with dynamic code based on the status of the instance. The status of the instance is returned by instance field `wf_state`.

Here is what we use in the model:

```
wf_validation_def = find_config_const('validation_string_for_status_new', 'model_name') if (wf_state == 'new')
eval(wf_validation_def) if (wf_state == 'new')
```

Here the validation string returned in `wf_validation_def` by `find_config_const` when status is `new`. The validation string is:

```
"validates :unit_price, :presence = true, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0} "
```

However the above code returns error in rspec:

```
.../activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method 'wf_state'
```

Tried `self.wf_state` and the error is the same. What's wrong with the code above?

Comment: Where is `wf_state` coming from? Is it from a form field from the client? If so, have you set something like `attr_accessible` in the model?

Comment: wf_state is model attribute and is after attr_accessible.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#grouping-conditional-validations